# Create Key Properties in anonymous type dynamicaly with TypeBuilder

Tags: .net, vb.net

I use TypeBuilder to create an anonymous type which is used as key
in Linq GroupBy Function.

```
Public Shared Function CreateAnonymousType(fieldNames As List(Of String), fieldTypes As Type()) As Type
    Dim anonymousType
    Dim anonymousTypeName As String = GetAnonymousTypeName(fieldTypes)
    Dim dynamicAnonymousType As TypeBuilder = dynamicModule.DefineType(anonymousTypeName, TypeAttributes.Public)

    For Each fieldName In fieldNames
        dynamicAnonymousType.DefineField(fieldName, fieldTypes(fieldNames.IndexOf(fieldName)), FieldAttributes.Public)
    Next

    Return dynamicAnonymousType.CreateType

End Function
```

Do you know how i can define the properties as Key Properties
something like **new With{Key .property1 .....**

Because if not Grouping is not working properly..

Comment: As mentioned before, the Type is `Sealed`. If you want to add properties, you need to generate Get/Set methods, using `Public`, `SpecialName` and `HideBySig` attributes.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand your answer.The class is sealed but what is the effect of that in what i want to do.I want to declare properties not methods in the anonymous type

Comment: Your Type is not Sealed. -- Properties are Getter/Setter methods in disguise. Not clear why you want to use TypeBuilder for this.

Comment: I understand what you mean.So if I implement the get/set methods then the anonymous type will override the equals and gethashcode to provide equality if the properties are equal.Because that is what i want. I use typebuilder because i create dynamically the Key(anonymous type) in a GroupBy linq method.I use expressions to construct the groupby body

Comment: You don't need TypeBuilder to generate an anonymous Type using LINQ, That Type is in-lined in the Lambda. -- When you use the `Key` keyword to define the Type's Properties, you [make the Type `Sealed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.typeattributes).